# DISTINCT on multiple columns

Tags: mysql

I have, `SELECT DISTINCT (first),second,third FROM table`

AND i want not only the first to be DISTINCT and the second to be DISTINCT to but the third to stay without DISTINCT , i tryed like that.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (first,second),third FROM table
```

And couple more things but didnt worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT  m.first, m.second, m.third -- and possibly other columns
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT  first, second
        FROM    mytable
        ) md
JOIN    mytable m
ON      m.id =
        (
        SELECT  id
        FROM    mytable mi
        WHERE   mi.first = md.first
                AND mi.second = md.second
        ORDER BY
                mi.first, mi.second, mi.third
        LIMIT 1
        )
```

Create an index on `(first, second, third)` for this to work fast.

Comment: This is a very interesting way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this post?

[Select distinct from multiple fields using sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546804/select-distinct-from-multiple-fields-using-sql)

They seem very similar, maybe you could try something like that?

Hope this helps!