# sql distinct, getting 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a simple message feature for my website but I couldn't get distinct datas from 2 columns (`**from**` column and `**to**` column)

[image]

you see examples datas on the picture

how can I get the return "1,4,23,45,345"?

Comment: Could you please post your query?

Comment: I need distinct datas in `from` and `to` columns

Comment: Please take a look here: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546804/select-distinct-from-multiple-fields-using-sql

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should to union both columns and then filter for distinct values:

```
select distinct T.from_to from
( select `from` as from_to
  from messages
  union
  select `to` as from_to
  from messages
) T
```

if you really need all in a comma separate string, use [GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT]](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) aggregation function.

**EDITED**:

You should mark as solution Gerald answer. After test union operator and reread [mysql union operator documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html), by default, mysql filter for distinct values:

```
mysql> create table ta( a int );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> insert into ta values (1),(1),(2);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> select * from ta
    -> union
    -> select * from ta;
+------+
| a    |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

then, the **final query** is:

```
  select `from` as from_to
  from messages
  union distinct
  select `to` as from_to
  from messages
```

Notice that `distinct` is not mandatory.

Only if you need a comma sparate string the first solution is necessary:

```
select distinct GROUP_CONCAT( distinct T.from_to from )
( select `from` as from_to
  from messages
  union
  select `to` as from_to
  from messages
) T
```

Comment: You do not need the outer distinct, as UNION selects distinct rows by default.  UNION ALL allows for duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

```
select from as ft from messages
union
select to as ft from messages
```

In MySQL union selects distinct rows by default.  You would use UNION ALL to allow for duplicates.